# Case-insensitive replace in pattern_replace

Tags: lucene, elasticsearch

I have pattern_replace token filter ([es docs](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-pattern-replace-charfilter.html))

```
'addressPattern' => array(
                'type' => 'pattern_replace',
                'pattern' => '(str\.|street|and many more like this)',
                'replacement' => '',
            ),
```

How to make match case-insensitive ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sorry that this answer is not timely, but I was searching for the problem of performing case-insenstive pattern matching in Elasticsearch. One way is you can use embedded flags:

`'pattern' => '(?i)(str\.|street|and many more like this)',`

An embedded flag uses the (?xyz) syntax, where xyz are flags. Other flags are 'u' for unicode case, 'm' for multiline, 's' for dotall, and more too. Usually i and s are the most useful flags, u can be useful too if working with non-English words. Note that an embedded flag is contextual - if you put it at the start of a group, it applies only within that group.

Lucene uses Java's standard library regex, so for more details refer to the [java docs for util.regex.Pattern](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#CASE_INSENSITIVE) or the [tutorial on java regex patterns](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/pattern.html).

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. In many cases the workaround mentioned does not suit the needs. @Blake Walsh: The inline flags in Java (which Lucene is written in) are called embedded flags. You can find the documentation here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

Answer (score 1):

You can include `lowercase filter` in `analyzer`. For example:

```
settings: {
  analysis: {
    tokenizer: {pattern_tokenizer: {... define your tokenizer here }}
    analyzer: {
      tokenizer: 'pattern_tokenizer',
      filter: ['lowercase'], 
      ....other details...

    }
  }
}
```

The point is to define `lowercase` filter in your analyzer.

If you are using `term` query to match your search then you need to convert the search term to lowercase and then apply the query.

Comment: my filter is "Character Filters". Character filters are used to preprocess the string of characters before it is passed to the tokenizer. It is too late to use analyzer filter :)

Comment: @angelkoilov True, but does it need to be applied before tokenization?  It looks like your needs would be served just as well using a [Pattern Replace Token Filter](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-pattern_replace-tokenfilter.html).

Comment: If it is applied before tokenization, chance for getting empty token is lower

Comment: ok, your answer is working workaround. Will mark it as 'accepted'. I Will open new question "how to remove empty tokens"